# 3.7v to 3.3v voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, esp8266, lithium-polymer

I want to use a **3.7v lithium-polymer battery** to power a **826۶ wifi** module in a mechatronic project. This module works with 3.3v and I'm not an electronic expert so I use modules to avoid mistakes and time saving.
Despite the fact that it looks like a pretty common problem, I can't find any module to buy. I don't know anything about circuit design but I can learn. So I'm looking for any cheap solution for this problem.

**using this:**

[image]

**to power this:**

[image]

Comment: Many ESP modules already contain a low-dropout regulator.  Check to see if your module is one of those.

Comment: Related/duplicates: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/313201/2028 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/38782/2028

Comment: It appears you have [this module.](https://udvabony.com/product/esp8266-al-cloud-inside/)  It claims to be 3.3V only, so a regulator of some kind is required.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this:  Your best bet is to use an MCP1700-3302E to take that 3.7 - 4.2v LiPo Battery output and convert it to 3.3v.  https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/mcp1700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for a low drop out linear regulator which will regulate the battery voltage to 3.3V

For example a [TC1262](https://www.mouser.dk/datasheet/2/268/21373b-68613.pdf) from Microchip has a drop out voltage of about 300mV at a normal current consumption of the ESP8266.

If you prefer a ready-made module instead take a look at AMS1117 3.3V modules on Ebay.

Comment: That's "a low drop out linear regulator."

Comment: The maximum dropout voltage of the TC1262 is 650mV...this won't work.

Comment: Indeed, but that is at a current draw of 0.5 A which is not the current consumption of an ESP8266.

Comment: Can you provide a link or citation for the maximum current of the ESP8266? Because in the "ESP8266 Hardware Design Guidelines" from Espressif Systems we see: "When using a single power supply, the recommended output current is 500 mA."

Comment: I had a look at this post: https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?t=3875 which indicates a maximum start up current of about 330mA.

Comment: I guess AMS1117 3.3V module is what I need. thank you.

Comment: An AMS1117 will NOT WORK for this, as it requires AT LEAST 4.75v as the input!!  If you use one of these, you will only get about 2.8v on the output.....don't ask me how I know this ;)

Answer (score 7):

A battery's voltage sags as it discharges and the LiPo type is no exception. A 3.7V LiPo battery falls to about 3.0V when fully discharged. You will want your project to continue operating over the full range of battery charge state so you might want to consider a buck-boost converter that can operate with an input voltage down to 3.0V to get maximum run-time for your project.

On ebay, there are power supply modules that use the TI TPS63020 buck-boost IC. I see one for about $10 that should meet your needs. This solution is also more efficient than an LDO so you'll get longer run-time. Good Luck!

Comment: A buck-boost regulator is the best choice, so you can exploit the full voltage range of the Li-ion cell. TI's TPS63020 is a very good one. I would avoid LDOs, too, since they are far too inefficient for battery-powered devices.

Comment: _"This solution is also more efficient than an LDO"_ - Dropping 3.7V to 3.3V using a linear regulator is 89% efficient. It's very possible for a buck(-boost) converter to be _less_ efficient.